# How to split an implementation of a trait into multiple files?

Tags: module, rust, traits

I started working with [ws](https://crates.io/crates/ws), and I would like to split the [Handler](https://ws-rs.org/api_docs/ws/trait.Handler.html) trait implementation into multiple files.

So I wrote this in one file, `on_open.rs`:

```rust
impl Handler for Client {
    fn on_open(&mut self, _: Handshake) -> Result<()> {
        println!("Socket opened");
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

And this in another file, `on_message.rs`:

```rust
impl Handler for Client {
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Message) -> Result<()> {
        println!("Server got message '{}'. ", msg);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

While compiling it I got the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `ws::handler::Handler` for type `models::client::Client`:
 --> src\sockets\on_message.rs:9:1
  |
9 | impl Handler for Client {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `models::client::Client`
  |
 ::: src\sockets\on_open.rs:8:1
  |
8 | impl Handler for Client {
  | ----------------------- first implementation here
```

I'd like to have the files to be separated so that each developer can work on a separate one.  Is there a way to achieve this or am I forced to have the full trait implementation in a single file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you can have multiple `impl` blocks for the same *object*, you can't have two which are exactly the same, hence the error of *conflicting implementations* indicated by [`E0119`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0119):

> Since a trait cannot be implemented multiple times, this is an error.

(If the trait could be *specialised* because it takes any number of generic type arguments the situation would be very much different because every specialisation would be a different `impl` block.  However even then you wouldn't be able to have the same specialisation implemented more than once.)

If you would like to split the *functionality* into separate files, you could do that, but in a slightly different way than you originally thought.  You could split the `Client`'s `impl` block instead of the `Handler` implementation as the following minimal and compilable example  demonstrates.  (Try it in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ccfeae4fc3ea1a393244cd204cbbb39)!)

As you can see, the `Handler` trait is implemented for `Client` in one place, but all the implementations of `Client` are split into multiple files/modules and the `Handler` implementation is just *referencing* those:

```rust
mod handler
{
    pub type Result<T> = ::std::result::Result<T, HandlerError>;

    pub struct HandlerError;

    pub trait Handler
    {
        fn on_open(&mut self, h: usize) -> Result<()>;
        fn on_message(&mut self, m: bool) -> Result<()>;
    }
}

mod client
{
    use super::handler::{ self, Handler };

    struct Client
    {
        h: usize,
        m: bool,
    }

    impl Handler for Client
    {
        fn on_open(&mut self, h: usize) -> handler::Result<()>
        {
            self.handle_on_open(h)
        }

        fn on_message(&mut self, m: bool) -> handler::Result<()>
        {
            self.handle_on_message(m)
        }
    }

    mod open
    {
        use super::super::handler;
        use super::Client;

        impl Client
        {
            pub fn handle_on_open(&mut self, h: usize) -> handler::Result<()>
            {
                self.h = h;
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }

    mod message
    {
        use super::super::handler;
        use super::Client;

        impl Client
        {
            pub fn handle_on_message(&mut self, m: bool) -> handler::Result<()>
            {
                self.m = m;
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Peter's answer, I re-wrote my code as below, and it is working fine:
`socket.rs`

```rust
use ws::Handler;
use crate::models::client::Client;
use ws::{Message, Request, Response, Result, CloseCode, Handshake};

impl Handler for Client {
    fn on_open(&mut self, hs: Handshake) -> Result<()> {
        self.handle_on_open(hs)
    }

    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Message) -> Result<()> {
        self.handle_on_message(msg)
    }

    fn on_close(&mut self, code: CloseCode, reason: &str) {
        self.handle_on_close(code, reason)
    }

    fn on_request(&mut self, req: &Request) -> Result<(Response)> {
        self.handle_on_request(req)
    }
}
```

`sockets/on_open.rs`

```rust
use crate::models::client::Client;

use crate::CLIENTS;
use crate::models::{truck::Truck};
use ws::{Result, Handshake};

impl Client {
    pub fn handle_on_open(&mut self, _: Handshake) -> Result<()> {
        println!("socket is opened");
        Ok(())
    }
}
```